# How to setup Notepad++ to highlight matching brackets?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I am using Notepad++ 7.8.4 64 bit on Windows 10.   I've tried a few different files (different extensions) and the set highlighting for matching brackets does not work.   In the Settings --> Style Configurator, Global Styles, I can set current line highlighting foreground/background and instantly see the change.

Brace highlight style does nothing.   If the current line highlighting is blue, I go to a single line with matching brackets, and put the cursor one on/next to one of them, they both turn white.   NOT the setting I chose.   No matter what I set the Brace highlight style to, it never works.

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong ?   Thank you.

Went to Notepad++ and oooops - I must be a conformist and have a Facebook or Google account.  Oh well.   Thank you for accepting me here.

Comment: For Java and PHP, the `{}` or `()` or `[]` match highlighting for me, what other extensions were tried, because you never said. I've never had to toggle anything, the matching has always worked for me, and I too have Windows 10 and the same Notepad++ version.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to disable these two settings:

1. Enable global foreground color
2. Enable global background color:

go to Menu > Style Configurator > Global Styles > Global override

Taken from https://superuser.com/questions/1208168/change-on-brace-highlight-style-does-not-take-effect-on-notepad

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Matijca Erceg works, but I am using dark mode and it makes a mess out of everything else. All text now has a gray background and anything I select is highlighted in a color that makes the white text invisible. Great for text matching, but unless there is a way to control the colors it uses, I'll have to switch it on and off.